# Xpath and Nokogiri: why can't I get this attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xpath, nokogiri

I am trying to parse HTML that looks like:

```
<p class="row">
            <span class="itemdate"> Jul 22</span>
            <span class="itemsep"> - </span> 
            <a href="http://newyork.craigslist.org/brk/abo/3102470187.html">$2000 / 3br - Three bedroom apartment/new renovtion</a>
            <span class="itemsep"> - </span>
            <span class="itempn"><font size="-1"> (Bushwick-L Train-Close to Williamsburg)</font></span>
            <span class="itempx"> <span class="p"> pic</span></span>
            <span class="itemcg" title="abo"> <small class="gc"><a href="/abo/">apts by owner</a></small></span>
        </p>
```

When I perform this call:

```
page.xpath("//p[contains(@class, 'row')]/a").first
```

I get a result like:

```
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3feea2631444 name="a" 
attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3feea2631390 name="href"
value="http://newyork.craigslist.org/brk/abo/3102470187.html">] 
children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3feea2630ad0 "$2000 / 3br - Three bedroom">]>
```

So by looking at the xpath docs I should be able to just return the url by doing something like:

```
page.xpath("//p[contains(@class, 'row')]/a@href").first
```

But I get this error:

```
Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError Exception: Invalid expression: 
//p[contains(@class, 'row')]/a@href
```

I know how to get the URL from the Nokogiri object, but I'd rather that the xpath search just return an array of URLs.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a slash, you need `.../a/@href`.